# Do sports drinks such as Powerade and Gatorade help prevent or shorten hangovers?

Tags: medical-science, physiology

Does drinking Powerade or Gatorade before, during or after consuming alcohol help prevent or eliminate hangovers? According to [this article](http://www.cbc.ca/news/trending/hangovers-cant-be-prevented-with-water-or-greasy-food-says-science-1.3210322) a pilot study was done that found nothing can help hangovers but stresses it was not a full study. I find it hard to believe the study proved that *nothing* can help a hangover, for example according [to this article](http://www.thewire.com/entertainment/2011/12/sciences-best-hangover-cures/46786/) some study found that fructose helps in someway even if not directly helping the symptoms.